# ASP:Textbox onchange is not working

Tags: asp.net

I put the simple code in ASP.net with two Text Boxes 
The text box does not working on Chrome but working on IE.
RequestValidator is working ok on both browsets. 
 When I trying to type something both text boxes (txtUserName/txtPassword) are seems to be disabled
in Chrome but it's working on IE.

```
<tr>
            <td>User Name</td>
            <td style="padding-left:20px">  <asp:TextBox id="txtUserName"  AutoPostBack=true runat="server" Width="80px"  Enabled="true"  /></td>
            <td style="padding-left:20px"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ForeColor="Red"  Enabled="true"  ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUserName"
                ErrorMessage="User Name is Mandatory">User Name is Mandatory</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>Password</td>
             <td style="padding-left:20px">  <asp:TextBox id="txtPassword" runat="server" Width="80px" TextMode="Password" /></td>
             <td style="padding-left:20px">  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ForeColor="Red" ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword"
                ErrorMessage="Password is Mandatory">Password is Mandatory</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: It's not really clear what your asking.  "*it's seems to be disabled*" - What's disabled?  Both textboxes, one textbox, something else entirely?  Are they disabled as soon as the page loads, as soon as you type into one of them, or something else?

Comment: Are you saying that the RequiredFieldValidator's error message didn't disappear on chrome even though after you typed the values in the text boxes?

Comment: No , the problem is that I can not type anything on a text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in css following line

```
* {
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: -moz-none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
```

I know that from my question is impossible to know

Answer (score -1):

If it is that the required field validator messages are not disappearing, try the following:

1. Remove the text from in between the opening and closing validator tag.
2. Add that text to the Text attribute of the
3. Add the attribute Display="Dynamic" -- that should show the error message when there is an error only.

Comment: I specified that I do not have problem with the Validator